# SSIS - Data consistency check

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date, ssis

I've been recently working with SSIS. I have created a work flow with the next specification:

[image]

I am using a derived column in this case because from the Oracle source I am having some dates like '0001-01-31' and '1500-02-031', and the idea is to transform these dates in '1900-01-01' (This is the expresion that I have used: [Date] < (DT_DBDATE)"1900-01-01" ? (DT_DBDATE)"1900-01-01" : [Date]) . Because the first kind of dates are not allowed by de sql database, and I can not change the specification of the data type of the column.

The problem is that when I look the data flow at the end of the execution it shows that 9.958 rows have been inserted in the destination, but making a query with a count select in sql over the database, the figure I'm having is 9.956. According with this, the rows that contains this dates have not been modified by the process.

So, I would like to know why is this happening, and if there is a way to get the result that I am looking for.
Thanks

Comment: What is the query you used in SQL? Also, which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: All of the components you have on your data flow are synchronous. That means that for each row that enters a component, exactly one row will be output. I suspect your two missing rows have a NULL that you're filtering against. Thus something like SELECT COUNT_BIG(1) AS rc FROM MyTable T WHERE T.[Date] IS NULL OR T.[Date] >= CAST('1900-01-01' AS date);

Comment: @billinkc  The two missing rows correspond to these dates. I have looked for them using the ID of the row and they are not in the destination datasource. The query that I used is a simple count query select(*) from table. I am using visual studio 2010 and sql server 2012

Comment: In your "SQL Destination", that's an OLE DB Destination. Is your Data access mode set to `Table or view - fast load` or just `Table or view` Default for 2008+ is the fast load option. Did you change the value for Rows per batch (default is blank) or Maximum insert commit size (default is 2147483647)?  Did you define an Error Output? I ask these things as your package should either blow up if it can't store all the data or you've set up error handling to prevent the failure

Comment: The issue is that Microsoft components don't recognise the same date range as Oracle does.  Even trying to compare the two objects as dates require you to translate the erroneous record to a date (which will fail).  I make Oracle pass in legitimate dates and take this work away from SSIS.